# How to export a THREE.JS scene into a 360 texture for photosphere

Tags: three.js, photosphere

Now that youtube supports 360 degree video[1], how can I export a  360 degree frame from THREE.JS scene to be viewable as a photosphere texture or even within a youtube video?

The viewer to use the export could be like the one at http://blog.thematicmapping.org/2014/01/photo-spheres-with-threejs.html

[image]

[image]

[2] http://www.wired.com/2015/03/youtube-360-degree-video/

https://support.solidangle.com/display/mayatut/Creating+a+Basic+Spherical+Camera
http://www.canadiannaturephotographer.com/sphericalpans.html
https://www.flickr.com/photos/sbprzd/4008650304/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is what I did.

I set up 6 cameras, captured each viewport and fed it into a 360 shader as texturecube.

Comment: Can you elaborate on your answer. I'm also currently trying to export a single equirectangular image from my THREE.js scene. Any help on how you ended up with the image would be appreciated.

Comment: @Mathias greetings fellow ACC member :) You may find this demo useful: http://envokevr.github.io/three-sixty/

Answer (score 3):

I put together a few different libraries to enable 360 video and photo capture from Three.js

https://github.com/imgntn/j360

Answer (score 0):

It seems you could render two frames from a 180FOV camera, the first aimed at (0,0,1), and the second at (0,0,-1). Next, stitch them into a single image.