# How to do a shader to convert to azimuthal_equidistant

Tags: geometry, glsl, projection

I have a [360 texture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29048161/how-to-export-a-three-js-scene-into-a-360-texture-for-photosphere/33012125#33012125) in Equirectangular Projection.

With what GLSL shader can I convert it into a [azimuthal equidistant projection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Azimuthal_equidistant_projection)?

See also:
http://earth.nullschool.net/#current/wind/isobaric/500hPa/azimuthal_equidistant=24.64,98.15,169

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**I would do it in Fragment shader.**

1. bind Equirectangular texture as 2D texture
2. bind projection shader
3. draw Quad covering the screen or target texture
4. store or use the result.

**In Vertex shader I would:**

Just pass the vertex coordinates as `varying` to fragment shader (no point using matrices here you can directly use x,y coordinates in range `<-1,+1>`)

**In fragment shader I would:**

1. compute `azimuth` and `distance` of interpolated `vertex` from point `(0,0)` (simple `length` and `atan2` call)
2. then convert them to `(u,v)` coordinates of texture (just scale...)
3. and lastly render fragment with selected texel or throw it out if out of range ...

**[edit1] just did bust a small example:**

**GL draw**

```
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

GLint id;
glUseProgram(prog_id);
id=glGetUniformLocation(prog_id,"txr"); glUniform1i(id,0);

glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glLoadIdentity();
glMatrixMode(GL_TEXTURE);
glLoadIdentity();
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glLoadIdentity();

glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D,txrmap);

glBegin(GL_QUADS);
glColor3f(1,1,1);
glVertex2f(-1.0,-1.0);
glVertex2f(-1.0,+1.0);
glVertex2f(+1.0,+1.0);
glVertex2f(+1.0,-1.0);
glEnd();
glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D,0);

glUseProgram(0);
glFlush();
SwapBuffers(hdc);
```

**Vertex:**

```
varying vec2 pos;
void main()
    {
    pos=gl_Vertex.xy;
    gl_Position=gl_Vertex;
    }
```

**Fragment:**

```
uniform sampler2D txr;
varying vec2 pos;
void main()
    {
    const float pi2=6.283185307179586476925286766559;
    vec4 c=vec4(0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0);
    vec2 uv;        // texture coord = scaled spherical coordinates
    float a,d;      // azimuth,distance
    d=length(pos);
    if (d<1.0)      // inside projected sphere surface
        {
        a=atan(-pos.x,pos.y);
        if (a<0.0) a+=pi2;
        if (a>pi2) a-=pi2;
        uv.x=a/pi2;
        uv.y=d;
        c=texture2D(txr,uv);
        }
    gl_FragColor=c;
    }
```

**Input texture:**

[image: earth rectangular]

**Output render:**

[image: earth azimuthal equidistant]

**[notes]**

The vertical line is caused by not using `GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE` on source texture. It can be repaired by using texture coordinates range shifted by 1 pixel on booth sides or use `GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE` extension if present.

Weird `atan()` operands are result of rotating left by 90 degrees to match North azimuth to be UP.

Comment: thanks! will try this and come back how it worked out soon enough