# Convert Cubemap coordinates to equivalents in Equirectangular

Tags: image, image-processing, geometry, projection, panoramas

I have a set of coordinates of a 6-image Cubemap (Front, Back, Left, Right, Top, Bottom) as follows:

```
[ [160, 314], Front; [253, 231], Front; [345, 273], Left; [347, 92], Bottom; ... ]
```

Each image is 500x500p, being [0, 0] the top-left corner.
I want to convert these coordinates to their equivalents in equirectangular, for a 2500x1250p image. The layout is like this:

[image: cubemap]

I don't need to convert the whole image, just the set of coordinates. Is there any straight-forward conversion por a specific pixel?

Comment: Are the coordinates you post relative to a common XYZ origin? What is equirectangular? Explaining these things you'll get more chances that somebody helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. **convert your image+2D coordinates to 3D normalized vector**

   the point `(0,0,0)` is the center of your cube map to make this work as intended. So basically you need to add the `U,V` direction vectors scaled to your coordinates to 3D position of texture point `(0,0)`. The direction vectors are just unit vectors where each axis has 3 options `{-1, 0 , +1}` and only one axis coordinate is non zero for each vector. Each side of cube map has one combination ... Which one depends on your conventions which we do not know as you did not share any specifics.
2. **use [Cartesian to spherical](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_coordinate_system) coordinate system transformation**

   you do not need the radius just the two angles ...
3. **convert the spherical angles to your 2D texture coordinates**

   This step depends on your 2D texture geometry. The simplest is rectangular texture (I think that is what you mean by  equirectangular) but there are other mappings out there with specific features and each require different conversion. Here few examples:

   - [Bump-map a sphere with a texture map](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32558700/2521214)
   - [How to do a shader to convert to azimuthal_equidistant](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33015271/2521214)

   For the rectangle texture you just scale the spherical angles into texture resolution size...

   ```
   U = lon * Usize/(2*Pi)
   V = (lat+(Pi/2)) * Vsize/Pi
   ```

   plus/minus some orientation signs to match your coordinate systems.

btw. just found this (possibly duplicate QA):

- [GLSL Shader to convert six textures to Equirectangular projection](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35050222/2521214)

Comment: Correct and well-explained solution.
My convention is like [this one](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/b4/Skybox_example.png), and I already adapted the unit vectors to it.
The final _V_ also depends if the pixel [0,0] is at the top-left corner or at the bottom-left. In this case it works for me, thanks.

Comment: @Finfa811 glad to be of help. I added the image to your Question (you can do it just by adding `!` before the link `![bla bla](link)` that will tell the site it is  an image ...