# How do I convert a panorama to spherical texture map?

Tags: unity-game-engine, opengl, graphics, 3d, direct3d

How do I go from panorama:

[image]

To this? *It would be great to know the exact name of this texture as well. Spherical texture map is the first thing that came to my mind.*

[image]

I've found this great tool to do a similar thing, but it is not what I need.

https://jaxry.github.io/panorama-to-cubemap/

[image]

Comment: From the function call `copyPixel(readData.width * lon / Math.PI / 2 - 0.5, readData.height * lat / Math.PI - 0.5, to);` it is clear that longitude and latitude vary linearly across the panorama, so it is even easier to convert this into a sphere map - compute the `(lon, lat)` of the ray and sample the pixel  with the formula above.

Comment: You can use the original image for a dual parabolic environment mapping. See [this paper](http://cgvr.cs.uni-bremen.de/teaching/cg_literatur/Spherical,%20Cubic,%20and%20Parabolic%20Environment%20Mappings.pdf)

Comment: see possible GLSL duplicate: [How to do a shader to convert to azimuthal_equidistant](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33015271/2521214)