# How to render a 360 stereo frame with glsl/webgl

Tags: glsl, virtual-reality

I am trying to render a frame for a video for vrideo.com or youtube.com.

For a mono 360 frame I get to use 6 THREEJS cameras and then stich them together.
[How to export a THREE.JS scene into a 360 texture for photosphere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29048161/how-to-export-a-three-js-scene-into-a-360-texture-for-photosphere)

Yet now its time to figure out stereo 360.

Has anybody figured out how to do it yet?

One option is to limit stereo only for the front camera and keep others mono.
[image]

An experiment with 12 directional stereo sprites:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zQOwywXEq4w

Today Google released Cardboard Camera that seems to be able to capture stereo 360 during rotation of the camera. It looks good. How did they do it?

Comment: additional ideas http://forums.vrideo.com/viewtopic.php?f=14&p=18

Comment: I removed your epilogue because all it's going to do is attract the very behaviour you don't want. Not sure whether and how this is programming related though?

Comment: It seems like the problem might be with your questions rather than the community, looking at examples like [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33277825/would-one-make-a-raymarch-shadertoy-of-this-semi-mirrored-house-in-the-desert) or [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33275151/how-to-make-a-laptop-to-lay-audio-on-a-virtual-output-serviced-by-a-pc-server)...

Comment: um. so Pekka you think its cool to down vote and not comment and not give an anwser? and then you think its cool to close or delete a comment for being too board or off topic? not cool.

Comment: What are you talking about?

Comment: The problem is that some of your questions tend to make an impression to common reader: **I need this do it for me** ... if you add some example what have you tried (or some ideas how to approach) and where you stuck it would be whole another matter but without it people just downvote/close.  Also recomendation of lib or any of-site stuff is of-topic (and for a good reason) ... Instead you can discuss concrete lib that is OK (but you still must becarefull to specify what exactly you need to know).

Answer (score 0):

ok. here is the idea.

a 4k stereo video is 3840 pixels wide for 360 left to right panorama.

so could the renderer render left and right eye for each pixel strip while it is in the center. by rotating the center.

this needs a prototype to see if it would actually work

**[added by Spektre]**

[image: 3D Stereoscopy cameras]

You Should place cameras so the center of rotation lies on their projection plane (Znear of frustrum). You can apply **Yaw** and **pitch** but not roll.
The camera position is in most rendering engines usually the focal point so you need to place them accordingly.

Comment: this might work but you need to constraint (or eliminate) the camera **roll** rotation while preview because that would distort the stereo 3D effect or needed separate feed for each roll rotation .... I think. So just place the cameras offseted from center by half of the eye distance to the left and right ... (average eye distance is ~6.5cm)

Comment: by roll you mean the stereo is limited to x axis only right?

Comment: no the cameras are. but if you roll the camera then the image between left and right camera is not just rotated and that can not be sainly encoded to the same image feed

Comment: k. will try. will need to do some test frames

Comment: I agree ... this is very hard to imagine ... also I would ofset both cameras not just the second otherwise while rotation you will see the distortion like you would go in circles unless the projection plane and objects are really far but that would be meaningless for the stereo scopy

Comment: added an image to your answer with what I have in mind

Comment: for reference: https://www.reddit.com/r/oculus/comments/1w52ti/i_wrote_a_little_script_that_renders_360_degree/

Comment: bump. Google Cardboard Camera seems to have figured it out.